# Missing Listing number in caption

Tags: captions, numbering, listings

My problem is that I don't have automatic listing numbers in the caption. (I thought they would be included by default and can't seem to find a way to include them)

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={test}, label={test}, 
title={test test test}, language=JavaScript, style=JavaScript]
import axios from 'axios';
console.log("hello world!");
\end{lstlisting}
```

This is an example listing code. This is how it looks right now:
[image]

Comment: Can you please send a complete MWE?

Comment: The manual says on page 19: _If you don't want the label Listing plus number, you should use title_.   So drop the the `title` key and rely only on the `caption`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ArashEsbati, that quickly solved my issue.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either the `caption` key or the `title` key, not both at the same time.  From `listings` manual:

> title = *title text*
> is used for a title without any numbering or label.
>
> caption = {[*short*]*caption text*}
> The caption is made of
> `\lstlistingname` followed by a running number, a separator, and
> *caption text*. Either the caption text or, if present, *short* will
> be used for the list of listings.

Simply drop the `title` key and you get a numbered caption.